# Automatically run a script when HBase master Docker container finishes initializing

Tags: docker, hbase, docker-compose

I'm trying to automate setting up a development environment for a web service that uses HBase using Docker containers. What I'd like to do is apply our schema to HBase once the container is up and HBase is started.

Trying to call a script that copies the schema over to HBase and immediately apply it via `./hbase shell` gives me an error that the master node isn't done initializing (I know that running this on the container leaves me in the hbase-cli prompt, but I'll deal with automatically returning from that once I get it running in the first place).

I've looked at tools like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) but I can't find a host/port combination to hit that will show as being "up" when the master node is initialized.

My question is, how can I poll my HBase container to see when the master node is initialized so I can apply my schema without watching the logs and manually running the command in the container itself?

Comment: What about a script to check the last 100 lines of hbase logs until the log ```master.HMaster: Master has completed initialization``` appears ?

Comment: any answer on this one? I am running into the same problem

Comment: Nope, sorry. I think I found some other hack-around, but I can't remember and I've since changed jobs. I also moved off that project around the time I finally got a reliable environment build working.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is a tough problem.  Here was our design at Splice Machine (Open Source), hope it helps...

(1) Create a MasterObserver (Coprocessor): This is a single point of entry for schema creation.

(2) Create calls from the region servers as they come up to call the master (Create Specific InitTable for example) if zookeeper does not find the schema initialized flag.

(3) Have the MasterObserver override preCreateTable and perform your schema creation there in a thread blocking manner(i.e. block other requests from region servers).  We did not want our JDBC/ODBC port up until our dictionary was initialized (schema) and also we wanted to make sure we had a region server available for the tables that are created.

(4) At the end of creation, have the MasterObserver write an initialized flag to zookeeper.  This is critical because it handles the partial create case that can happen when bouncing servers quickly, etc.

Code example:

MasterObserver Code Snippet

```
@Override
    public void preCreateTable(ObserverContext<MasterCoprocessorEnvironment> ctx, HTableDescriptor desc, HRegionInfo[] regions) throws IOException {
        SpliceLogUtils.info(LOG, "preCreateTable %s", Bytes.toString(desc.getTableName().getName()));
        if (Bytes.equals(desc.getTableName().getName(), INIT_TABLE)) {
            switch(manager.getState()){
                case NOT_STARTED:
                    boot();
                case BOOTING_ENGINE:
                case BOOTING_GENERAL_SERVICES:
                case BOOTING_SERVER:
                    throw new PleaseHoldException("Please Hold - Starting");
                case RUNNING:
                    throw new DoNotRetryIOException("Success");
                case STARTUP_FAILED:
                case SHUTTING_DOWN:
                case SHUTDOWN:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Startup failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Feel free to check out

RegionLifecycleObserver and SpliceMasterObserver on our github account.

https://github.com/splicemachine/spliceengine

Good luck.